# How to add Filtering to Josh Smith's MVVM msdn design

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have mimicked Josh Smith's design from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx and would like to add filtering.

In the AllCustomersViewModel he creates an ObservableCollection of CustomerViewModel, which is linked to the xaml via the property AllCustomers

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> AllCustomers { get; private set; }
```

In the xaml AllCustomers is set as a CollectionViewSource.

In saying this, I would like advise on how to extend this functionality to include filtering. I am not to worried about the xaml side of things, more implementing it in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need `CollectionViewSource` at all to be defined in XAML. It can be done all in your ViewModel.

Directly bind collection to ListBox in your XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomers}"/>
```

and in ViewModel you can apply ***filter by getting default CollectionView*** related to your collection like this:

```
ICollectionView defaultCollectionView = CollectionViewSource
                                       .GetDefaultView(AllCustomers);
defaultCollectionView.Filter = p => ((CustomerViewModel)p).IsCompany;
```

Assuming `IsCompany` is a bool property. Filter takes predicate (*you can replace it with any delegate returning bool*).

On a side note you can also apply sorting and grouping from ViewModel itself.

---

If you want to have `CollectionViewSource` in XAML, you can apply filter in code-behind.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCVS"
                      Source="{Binding AllCustomers}"
                      Filter="MyCVS_Filter"/>
```

and in code behind:

```
void MyCVS_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    CustomerViewModel item = e.Item as CustomerViewModel;
    if (item.IsCompany)
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I am planning to use a popup as well to filter, I was thinking of just using one generic popup for all my columns. There will be a list of distinct values with checkboxes, the values will change depending on the column being filtered. That's why I asked about getting the parameter for the column binding property name in my other question. Somehow creating an individual filter for each column seems too convoluted. How would you proceed?

Comment: I will clarify that a little, I'm looking to create one generic filter with values loaded dynamically for each of my columns.